# Drawing on canvas - not following the mouse path

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, canvas

I have a problem with my code and I hope that someone will be able to help me.
I'm doing an application that enables to draw on the touchscreens or with the use of a mouse for few people simultaneously.

The problem is that my code check positions of a cursor periodically (it looks like that but I don't have any periodic checking in code) because when drawing fast I can see something like that (lines are too straight and they doesn't follow the cursor path):
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ehF.png)

Here's a code:
`https://jsfiddle.net/Kshishiu/reyagxtz/4/`

```
function getTouchPos (canvasDom, touchEvent) {
    var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect ();
    return {
        x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
        y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top,
    };
}
```

I appreciate any input from You :)

Thanks! <3

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try it with this method:

```
var holding = false;
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", ()=>{
   holding = true;
}
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", ()=>{
   holding = true;
}
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", ()=>{
   holding = false;
}
document.body.addEventListener("touchend", ()=>{
   holding = false;
}
```

Then you can track your canvas moves:

```
document.getElementById("yourCanvasId").addEventListener("mousemove", ()=>{
   if(holding == true){
      x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      y = event.clientY - rect.top;
   }
}

document.getElementById("yourCanvasId").addEventListener("touchmove", ()=>{
   if(holding == true){
      x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      y = event.clientY - rect.top;
   }
}
```

With socket.io you could emit these moving events to your server, and your server send these information to all your clients and on the client side you could write a small script where you can listen to these events and draw something depending on these events.

Comment: Unfortunately, even after making this changes it doesn't work. Still tracks way too less points :(